# how can I add html extra code in ajax database table columns

Tags: node.js, ajax

my code

```
      $(document).ready(() => {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:10001/etiketokuyucu", 
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
          console.log(response[0]);
            if(response.length > 0){
                for(let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
                    var newRow = $("<tr>");
                    var cols = "";
                    var okuyucu = '';
                    var x = '';
                    var y = '';
                    cols += '<td> '+ response[index].okuyucu +'</td>' ;
                    cols += '<td> '+ response[index].x +'</td>';
                    cols += '<td> '+ response[index].y +'</td>'; 
newRow.append(cols);
                $("#example .tbody").append(newRow);
            }  

        }
    }
})
})
```

I want to add extra cols to add, edit and remove function in my table but I couldn't.

I want to add these lines

```
<td class="text-right">
                              <div class="dropdown d-inline-block widget-dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle icon-burger-mini" href="" role="button" id="dropdown-recent-order1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-display="static"></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdown-recent-order1">
                                  <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <a href="#">View</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <a href="#">Remove</a>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                            </td>
```

How can I do this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem in this way

```
 $(document).ready(() => {

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:10001/etiketokuyucu", 
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response[0]);
        if(response.length > 0){
            for(let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
                var newRow = $("<tr>");
                var cols = "";
                var okuyucu = '';
                var x = '';
                var y = '';
                cols += '<td> '+ response[index].okuyucu +'</td>' ;
                cols += '<td> '+ response[index].x +'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response[index].y +'</td>'; 
             cols += '<td>' 
              +
                              '<div class="dropdown d-inline-block widget-dropdown">'+
                                '<a class="dropdown-toggle icon-burger-mini" href="" role="button" id="dropdown-recent-order1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-display="static"></a>'+
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdown-recent-order1">'+
                                 '<li class="dropdown-item">'+
                                    '<a href="#">View</a>'+
                                  '</li>'+
                                  '<li class="dropdown-item">'+
                                    '<a href="#">Remove </a>'+
                                  '</li>'+
                                '</ul>'+
                              '</div>'+
                            '</td>' ;        
                newRow.append(cols);
                $("#example .tbody").append(newRow);
            }  

        }
    }
})
```

})